# Using IFFT for the purpose of "Multiple Orthogonal Frequency Shift Keying"

Tags: digital-communications

Is it possible to create a set of complex orthogonal sinusoids using FFT or IFFT 
In other words a kind of  "Multiple Frequency Shift Keying" using  multiple sinusoids that are created with a fourier transform ( FFT or IFFT) and where one frequency is sent at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically this is OFDM with an on/off constellation for each subcarrier instead of a QAM constellation as often used. So you would map your data to FFT values (each FFT bin is either 1 or 0), then take the IFFT to create the transmit waveform, with the cyclic prefix etc as in standard OFDM implementations.

Comment: I would think of this more as an OFDM - OOK approach (On/Off keying) rather than frequency shift keying since we typically think of each frequency bin in the FFT as its own sub-carrier. I guess you could instead call the frequency between two bins as a subcarrier and use 2 bins for the modulation as a true FSK signal. The result is the same it is just a matter of how you want to map the data and how you want to conceptualize what you are doing. Either of these approaches would be unusual so likely more a point of fun discussion.

Comment: I don't see the advantage of using an OOK approach vs the closest alternative of BPSK for transmitting one bit/symbol; we would choose BPSK (or QPSK) over a typical QAM mapping when consideration is more toward power efficiency vs spectral efficiency.

Comment: I would want to think that sending one sinusoid at a time has certain advantages especially in a situation where data rate is very low and where orthogonality is needed so that a receiver can distinguish between one sinusoid and  another one since every sinusoid is carrying a different kind of information (without being modulated,  but by means of a look up table known for the transmitter and the receiver) so when the receiver FFT's the incoming signal (it has been IFFT'd at the transmit) only the sinusoid that was sent will pop up

Comment: I am not sure I completely follow, do you think that if we sent ALL the sub-carriers at the same time the receiver could not distinguish them? They are orthogonal and therefore we can transmit them simultaneously and the receiver can distinguish each. Further when we decide to use multiple options for the symbol in the subcarrier, we still are only transmitting one of those symbols at a time- within that subcarrier. So first thing to be clear on, we can send ALL the subcarriers at the same time- that is no issue in a linear channel.

Comment: So for a "BPSK" subcarrier, you decide to either send +1 or -1 corresponding to bit 1 or bit 0. So if I wanted to send the sequence 10110, the FFT coefficients would be 1 -1 1 1 -1. What specifically are you proposing to send instead in this case? Five separate FFT blocks one at a time? What would they be?

Comment: every subcarrier represents finite information expressed by a symbol of say 4 bits, meaning that I have 16 sets of information that would require 16 subcarrier .So for example suppose 0 1 1 0 means "Good morning" and by means of a look up table it has been assigned to  subcarrier number 2, subcarrier 2 is sent , and upon doing an IFFT at the receiver, it will be identified, a corresponding look up table at the receiver would know that if subcarrier 2 was sent it means symbol 0110 which in its turn means "Good morning"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84752/discussion-between-dan-boschen-and-hatem-tawfik).